# C syntax for String manipulation advice?

Tags: c, string, syntax

I got a very simple questions in regards to C syntax.

I am trying to merge some static strings with a dynamic strings.

For example I got a C function which has the following prototype:

```
uint8_t AT_feedback_checker(const char my_str[], const char ATcmd[],
                            uint32_t time_out_ms, uint8_t mode);
```

I am calling my function as

```
if (AT_feedback_checker(PSTR("OK"), PSTR("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://djblob.blob.net/mycontainer/myFirstDevicea.txt\" "),2000,0) == AT_REPLY_STATUS_FOUND_AT_REPLY)
```

I would like to change the file name part of the string dynamically.

For example `a.txt`, or `b.txt` (instead of `myFirstDevicea.txt`). The file name can change.

How can I set up the function or syntax so the starting part of the string is a specific text and remaining part can be anything I choose such as a file name?

Can someone show me an example?

Comment: I think you've been confused. You can pass a variable string to a function that takes a const char[]. You cannot pass a constant string to one that takes a variable char [].

Answer (score 1):

The classic C idiom would be to use a temporary string and tools like `snprintf`:

```
char cmd[128];  // choose a "large enough" size
snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd,
    PSTR("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://djblob.blob.net/mycontainer/%s\" "),
    file_name);
if (AT_feedback_checker(PSTR("OK"), cmd, 2000, 0)
    == AT_REPLY_STATUS_FOUND_AT_REPLY)
  ...
```

`snprintf` will avoid overrunning the temporary buffer in case the file name is too large. In production code you would also check the return value of `snprintf` and report an error in that case.